# i want to make the price table appear after check id ( success ) I try but always error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've tried merging or changing using if else , but always getting a result error

html code

```
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="ps-3">Beli</h1>
  <!-- form -->
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">ID Character</label>
      <input name="nomor" placeholder="1234567" type="text" class="form-control" id="id_character" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">ID Zone</label>
      <input name="id_zone" placeholder="1234" type="text" class="form-control" id="id_zone">
    </div>
    <button id="button_beli" class="button_beli btn btn-primary" type="button">
        <span id="button_beli_loading" class="d-none spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        Beli Sekarang
    </button>

</div>
```

> if you use this javascript then just check the id

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".button_beli").click( function() {
  $("#button_beli_loading").removeClass('d-none');
  var id_character = $("#nomor").val();
  var id_zone = $("#id_zone").val();
  if (id_character.length == "") {
      $("#button_beli_loading").addClass('d-none');
      Swal.fire({
          type: 'warning',
          title: 'Oops...',
          text: 'Character ID Wajib Diisi !'
      });
  }else{
    //ajax
    $.ajax({
      url: "api.php",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: 'JSON',
      data: {
          "id": id_character,
          "server": id_zone
      },
      success:function(response){
        $("#button_beli_loading").addClass('d-none');
        //
        var response_status = response.status;
        var nama = response.nama;
        var id = response.id;
        var zone = response.zone;
        var output = nama + "\n" + id;
        //
        if (response.status == "ok"){
            Swal.fire({
              type: 'success',
              text: output
            });
            $("#id_character").val('');
            $("#id_zone").val('');
        }else if(response.status == "error_1"){
            Swal.fire({a
              type: 'error',
              text: 'ID tidak ditemukan, coba lagi!'
            });
        }else{
            Swal.fire({
              type: 'error',
              text: 'Error, coba lagi!'
            });
        }
        console.log(response);
      },
      error:function(response){
          $("#button_beli_loading").addClass('d-none');
          Swal.fire({
            type: 'error',
            text: 'server error!'
          });
      }
    })
  }
});
```

i want to combine with javascript which shows the price table after filling the number with check id
how to do so that after checking the response id is successful, the price list appears?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
           $('#tabl').hide();
    // $('#nomor').attr('disabled','disabled');
    $('.exs').hide();
    // $("#tipe").change(function() {
    //  $('#nomor').val('');
    //  var tipe = $("#tipe").val();
    //  if($(this).val() != 0){
    //      // $('#nomor').removeAttr('disabled');
    //  }
    //     // $.ajax({
    //     //  url: '<?php echo $config['web']['url']; ?>ajax/type-top-up.php',
    //     //  data: 'tipe=' + tipe,
    //     //  type: 'POST',
    //     //  dataType: 'html',
    //     //  success: function(msg) {
    //     //   $("#operator").html(msg);
    //     //  }
    //     // });
    //    });

    // $("#operator").change(function() {
    //     var tipe = $("#tipe").val();
    //  var operator = $("#operator").val();
    //  $.ajax({
    //   url: '<?php echo $config['web']['url']; ?>ajax/service-top-up.php',
    //   data  : 'tipe=' +tipe + '&operator=' + operator,
    //   type: 'POST',
    //   dataType: 'html',
    //   success: function(msg) {
    //    $("#layanan").html(msg);
    //   }
    //  });
    // });
    $('.exs').click(function() {
        $('.exs').hide();
        $('#panel_list').removeClass('isi_p');
        $('#ajx').hide();
        $('#rep').show();
 
       
    });

    $('#nomor').on('keyup change input', function(e) {
        var char = $(this).val().length;
        if (char == 0) {
            $('#tabl').hide();
            normal();
        } else {
            $('#panel_list').addClass('isi_p');
            $('#ajx').show();
            $('#tls').hide();
             $('#tabl').show();
        }
        if ($('#tipe').val() != '') {
            $('.type_l').html("");

            var nmr = $(this).val().split("");
            if (nmr[0] == '+') {
                nomor($(this).val(), 6);
            } else if (nmr[0] == '1') {
                nomor($(this).val(), 5);
            } else if (nmr[0] == '2') {
                nomor($(this).val(), 5);
            }else if (nmr[0] == '3') {
                nomor($(this).val(), 5);
            }else if (nmr[0] == '4') {
                nomor($(this).val(), 5);
            }else if (nmr[0] == '5') {
                nomor($(this).val(), 5);
            }else if (nmr[0] == '6') {
                nomor($(this).val(), 5);
            }else if (nmr[0] == '7') {
                nomor($(this).val(), 5);
            }else if (nmr[0] == '8') {
                nomor($(this).val(), 5);
            }else if (nmr[0] == '9') {
                nomor($(this).val(), 5);
            }else if (nmr[0] == '0') {
                nomor($(this).val(), 5);
            }else {

            }
        } else {
            if (empty(char)) {
                $('.type_l').html("")
            } else {
                $('.type_l').html("<p style='color:red;'>pilih tipe Layanan</>")
            }

        }
    });

    $('#nomor').click(function() {
        
        $('.exs').show();
        $('#panel_list').addClass('isi_p');
        $('#ajx').show();
        $('#rep').hide();
    });
    normal();

    function normal() {
        $('.exs').hide();
      
        $('#panel_list').removeClass('isi_p');
        $('#ajx').hide();
         $('#tls').show();
    }

    function nomor(nomor, lengths) {
        var tipe = $('#tipe').val();
        var swit = 'reqnmr';
        var nomor = nomor;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo $config['web']['url']; ?>ajax/request-Operator.php",
            data: {
                nomor: nomor,
                tipe: tipe,
                swit: swit
            },
            success: function(response) {
                var res = $.parseJSON(response);
                var data = '';
                var no = 1;
                for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                    // var la = ((res[i]['layanan'].split(" ").length == 2)?res[i]['layanan'].split(" ")[1]:res[i]['layanan']);
                    var la = res[i]['layanan'];
                    data += '<div class="col-12 list_pls" style="cursor:pointer "'
                    data += 'data-layanan="' + la +
                        '"data-harga="' + res[i]['harga'] +
                        '"data-operator="' + res[i]['operator'] +
                        '"data-id="' + res[i]['id'] +
                        '"data-service_id="' + res[i]['service_id'] +
                        '"data-tipe="' + res[i]['tipe'] +
                        '"data-deskripsi="' + res[i]['deskripsi'] + '">'
                    data += '<div class="card mb-3 clasesItem" style="border:1px solid #ccc;" >'
                    data += '<div class="card-body " >'
                    data += '<h6 class="card-title m-0" >' + la + ' <span style="float: right; color: #fb4802;" >' + format(res[i]['harga']) + '</span></h6>'
                    data += '<p class="card-text" >' + res[i]['deskripsi'] + '</p>'
                    data += ' </div>'
                    data += '</div>'
                    data += '</div>'
                }
                $('#ajx').html(data);
                $('.list_pls').click(function() {
                    $('#rep').show();
                    $('#layanan').val($(this).data('service_id'));
                    normal();
                    layanan($(this).data('service_id'));
                    $('#operator').val($(this).data('operator'));
                    //requstOp($(this).data('tipe'),$(this).data('operator'));
                    rep = '<div class="col-12 " style="cursor:pointer">'
                    rep += '<div class="card mb-3" style="border:1px solid #ccc; color: #fff; background-color: #039dfc;">'
                    rep += '<div class="card-body">'
                    rep += '<h6 class="card-title m-0" id="harga">' + $(this).data('layanan') + '<span style="float: right; color: #fb4802;">' + format(parseInt($(this).data('harga'))) + '</span></h6>'
                    rep += '<p class="card-text">' + $(this).data('deskripsi') + '</p>'
                    rep += ' </div>'
                    rep += '</div>'
                    rep += '</div>'
                    $('#rep').html(rep);
                })
            }
        });

    }

    function layanan(layanan_) {
        var tipe = $("#tipe").val();
        var layanan = layanan_;

        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo $config['web']['url']; ?>ajax/rate-order-coins-top-up.php',
            data: 'layanan=' + layanan,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(msg) {
                $("#koin").html(msg);
                //console.log(msg);
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo $config['web']['url']; ?>ajax/price-top-up.php',
            data: 'layanan=' + layanan,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(msg) {
                $("#harga").val(msg);
            }
        });
    }

    function requstOp(tipe, kode) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo $config['web']['url']; ?>ajax/request-Operator.php',
            data: {
                tipe: tipe,
                kode: kode,
                swit: 'reqOpr'
            },
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(msg) {
                $('#operator').val(msg);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

i tried to combine like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
           $('#tabl').hide();
    // $('#nomor').attr('disabled','disabled');
    $('.exs').hide();
    // $("#tipe").change(function() {
    //  $('#nomor').val('');
    //  var tipe = $("#tipe").val();
    //  if($(this).val() != 0){
    //      // $('#nomor').removeAttr('disabled');
    //  }
    //     // $.ajax({
    //     //  url: '<?php echo $config['web']['url']; ?>ajax/type-top-up.php',
    //     //  data: 'tipe=' + tipe,
    //     //  type: 'POST',
    //     //  dataType: 'html',
    //     //  success: function(msg) {
    //     //   $("#operator").html(msg);
    //     //  }
    //     // });
    //    });

    // $("#operator").change(function() {
    //     var tipe = $("#tipe").val();
    //  var operator = $("#operator").val();
    //  $.ajax({
    //   url: '<?php echo $config['web']['url']; ?>ajax/service-top-up.php',
    //   data  : 'tipe=' +tipe + '&operator=' + operator,
    //   type: 'POST',
    //   dataType: 'html',
    //   success: function(msg) {
    //    $("#layanan").html(msg);
    //   }
    //  });
    // });
    $('.exs').click(function() {
        $('.exs').hide();
        $('#panel_list').removeClass('isi_p');
        $('#ajx').hide();
        $('#rep').show();
 
       
    });

$(".button_beli").click( function() {
        var char = $("#nomor").val();
          //ajax
    $.ajax({
      url: "api.php",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: 'JSON',
      data: {
          "id": id_character,
          "server": id_zone
      },
      success:function(response){
        $("#button_beli_loading").addClass('d-none');
        //
        var response_status = response.status;
        var nama = response.nama;
        var id = response.id;
        var zone = response.zone;
        var output = nama + "\n" + id;
        //
        if (response.status == "ok"){
            Swal.fire({
              type: 'success',
              text: output
            });
            $("#id_character").val('');
            $("#id_zone").val('');
        }else if(response.status == "error_1"){
            Swal.fire({a
              type: 'error',
              text: 'ID tidak ditemukan, coba lagi!'
            });
        }else{
            Swal.fire({
              type: 'error',
              text: 'Error, coba lagi!'
            });
        }
        console.log(response);
      },
      error:function(response){
          $("#button_beli_loading").addClass('d-none');
          Swal.fire({
            type: 'error',
            text: 'server error!'
          });
        if (char < 5) {
            $('#ajx').hide();
            $('#tls').show();
             $('#tabl').hide();
            normal();
             Swal.fire({
          type: 'warning',
          title: 'Oops...',
          text: 'Character ID Wajib Diisi !'
      });
        } else {
            $('#panel_list').addClass('isi_p');
            $('#ajx').show();
            $('#tls').hide();
             $('#tabl').show();
        }
        if ($('#tipe').val() != '') {
            $('.type_l').html("");

            var nmr = $("#nomor").val();
            if (nmr[0] == '+') {
                nomor($(this).val(), 6);
            } else if (nmr[0] == '1') {
                nomor($(this).val(), 5);
            } else if (nmr[0] == '2') {
                nomor($(this).val(), 5);
            }else if (nmr[0] == '3') {
                nomor($(this).val(), 5);
            }else if (nmr[0] == '4') {
                nomor($(this).val(), 5);
            }else if (nmr[0] == '5') {
                nomor($(this).val(), 5);
            }else if (nmr[0] == '6') {
                nomor($(this).val(), 5);
            }else if (nmr[0] == '7') {
                nomor($(this).val(), 5);
            }else if (nmr[0] == '8') {
                nomor($(this).val(), 5);
            }else if (nmr[0] == '9') {
                nomor($(this).val(), 5);
            }else if (nmr[0] == '0') {
                nomor($(this).val(), 5);
            }else {

            }
        } else {
            if (empty(char)) {
                $('.type_l').html("")
            } else {
                $('.type_l').html("<p style='color:red;'>pilih tipe Layanan</>")
            }

        }
    });


$(".button_beli").click( function() {
        
        $('.exs').show();
        $('#panel_list').addClass('isi_p');
        $('#ajx').show();
        $('#rep').hide();
    });
    normal();

    function normal() {
        $('.exs').hide();
      
        $('#panel_list').removeClass('isi_p');
        $('#ajx').hide();
         $('#tls').show();
    }

    function nomor(nomor, lengths) {
        var tipe = $('#tipe').val();
        var swit = 'reqnmr';
        var nomor = $('#nomor').val();;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo $config['web']['url']; ?>ajax/request-Operator.php",
            data: {
                nomor: nomor,
                tipe: tipe,
                swit: swit
            },
            success: function(response) {
                var res = $.parseJSON(response);
                var data = '';
                var no = 1;
                for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                    // var la = ((res[i]['layanan'].split(" ").length == 2)?res[i]['layanan'].split(" ")[1]:res[i]['layanan']);
                    var la = res[i]['layanan'];
                    data += '<div class="col-12 list_pls" style="cursor:pointer "'
                    data += 'data-layanan="' + la +
                        '"data-harga="' + res[i]['harga'] +
                        '"data-operator="' + res[i]['operator'] +
                        '"data-id="' + res[i]['id'] +
                        '"data-service_id="' + res[i]['service_id'] +
                        '"data-tipe="' + res[i]['tipe'] +
                        '"data-deskripsi="' + res[i]['deskripsi'] + '">'
                    data += '<div class="card mb-3 clasesItem" style="border:1px solid #ccc;" >'
                    data += '<div class="card-body " >'
                    data += '<h6 class="card-title m-0" >' + la + ' <span style="float: right; color: #fb4802;" >' + format(res[i]['harga']) + '</span></h6>'
                    data += '<p class="card-text" >' + res[i]['deskripsi'] + '</p>'
                    data += ' </div>'
                    data += '</div>'
                    data += '</div>'
                }
                $('#ajx').html(data);
                $('.list_pls').click(function() {
                    $('#rep').show();
                    $('#layanan').val($(this).data('service_id'));
                    normal();
                    layanan($(this).data('service_id'));
                    $('#operator').val($(this).data('operator'));
                    //requstOp($(this).data('tipe'),$(this).data('operator'));
                    rep = '<div class="col-12 " style="cursor:pointer">'
                    rep += '<div class="card mb-3" style="border:1px solid #ccc; color: #fff; background-color: #039dfc;">'
                    rep += '<div class="card-body">'
                    rep += '<h6 class="card-title m-0" id="harga">' + $(this).data('layanan') + '<span style="float: right; color: #fb4802;">' + format(parseInt($(this).data('harga'))) + '</span></h6>'
                    rep += '<p class="card-text">' + $(this).data('deskripsi') + '</p>'
                    rep += ' </div>'
                    rep += '</div>'
                    rep += '</div>'
                    $('#rep').html(rep);
                })
            }
        });

    }

    function layanan(layanan_) {
        var tipe = $("#tipe").val();
        var layanan = layanan_;

        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo $config['web']['url']; ?>ajax/rate-order-coins-top-up.php',
            data: 'layanan=' + layanan,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(msg) {
                $("#koin").html(msg);
                //console.log(msg);
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo $config['web']['url']; ?>ajax/price-top-up.php',
            data: 'layanan=' + layanan,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(msg) {
                $("#harga").val(msg);
            }
        });
    }

    function requstOp(tipe, kode) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo $config['web']['url']; ?>ajax/request-Operator.php',
            data: {
                tipe: tipe,
                kode: kode,
                swit: 'reqOpr'
            },
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(msg) {
                $('#operator').val(msg);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I've tried to combine but always error is there any solution?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcwuM.gif)

Comment: What's the error(s)?

Comment: You need look at console to get error